# Unable to get permissions to work properly

Tags: getstream-io

I'm messing around with permissions and am unable to figure out what's going on. I created a custom chat type, `gallery`, with permissions that look like this:

```
[
    {
        "action": "Deny",
        "name": "No access",
        "resources": [
            "*"
        ],
        "roles": [
            "*"
        ],
        "owner": false,
        "priority": 999
    }
]
```

So basically, nobody can do anything.

Now, to test this, I create a `gallery` channel with a user:

```
const client = new StreamChat(<STREAM_KEY>);
const token = <TOKEN>

chatClient.setUser(
  {
    id: 'user1',
    name: 'User 1',
  },
  token,
);

const channel = client.channel('gallery', 'example', {
  name: 'Example',
});
```

Using the React UI kit, `user1` (or any user) should NOT be able to view the channel given the permissions, right? And yet the channel loads and I can type messages normally. What am I doing wrong? I don't think being an `owner` or not matters, as I've tested this with two different users.

Comment: Is your app is in dev mode and permissions disabled ? Pleas, check if permissions are enabled in dashboard.

Comment: @ferhatelmas Oh I didn't even know that was an option, but it looks like the app is in production mode

Comment: Good to hear, it's resolved. We will update docs and error message to mention it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @ferhatelmas for the heads up. Though my app was in production mode, I noticed a toggle that was ON that disabled permissions. I toggled it off and I think everything seems to be OK.

[image]